# AM / PM value not displaying correctly in Select attribute

Tags: php, date, time, html-select

I have a list of items, each with a date/time option.  I need for each list item to have the correct time displayed for it.

But this doesn't seem to work.  It will return the correct 'am' or 'pm' value for $duedateA, but when I try to set the selected attribute value is gets wonky and will either show the wrong am or pm, or both.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
if(!empty($resInvoice[0]["due_date"])){
$duedateA = date("a",strtotime($resInvoice[0]['due_date']));
}       
if($duedateA == "am"){
$selected_am = 'selected="selected"';
}
if($duedateA == "pm"){
$selected_pm = 'selected="selected"';
}   

<select name="due_time[a]">
<option value="am" '.$selected_am.'>am</option>
<option value="pm" '.$selected_pm.'>pm</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you show the HTML?

Comment: this seems to work for me when i set $resInvoice[0]['due_date'] = time(); can you give an example of $resInvoice[0]['due_date']

Comment: Is the html at the bottom being echoed through php or is it outside the php tags?

Comment: @SamuelCook 2012-10-26 03:21:44 like so?

Comment: perfect. this still seems to work for me. code posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$resInvoice[0]["due_date"] = '2012-10-26 03:21:44';
$selected_am = '';
$selected_pm = '';
$duedateA = '';
if(!empty($resInvoice[0]["due_date"])){
    $duedateA = date("a",strtotime($resInvoice[0]["due_date"]));
}       
if($duedateA == "am"){
    $selected_am = ' selected="selected"';
}
if($duedateA == "pm"){
    $selected_pm = ' selected="selected"';
}

echo '<select name="due_date[a]">
    <option value="am"'.$selected_am.'>AM</option>
    <option value="pm"'.$selected_pm.'>PM</option>
</select>';
```

sorry for all the variables, i have my errors set to strict.

Comment: Excellent.  Problem solved!  I guess I forgot to declare my empty variables.  Thanks!